# How to simulate Call in Android phone without Sim card or Modem

Tags: android

I want to simulate Call feature in android phone without using Sim Card. I know in android framework class Parcel.java is communicating to Native RIL layer in android. So can I use this class to simulate Call Features in Phone? I need sample application.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is not possible. RIL can only be initialized if there is a modem and call can only be made if there is a SIM attached to the modem.